Issue in Multicolumn table
I always find it difficult to create a table on Latex that fits my requirements. Below is the table I currently have and you find the latex script used to create it.
I have two issues:

I would like to create 3 sub-columns under the columns 5-7 (RRMSE - Relative errors in blocks) each. I dont' know how to do this.
I also see that the column 2 heading "M" is slightly misaligned and don't know how to correct it.


\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \caption{Performance on Test Data}
  \label{tbl:sim}
    \begin{tabular}{*{16}{p{0.1\linewidth}}}
    \multicolumn{16}{c}{A. Polynomial and Training sample, $N=10000$} \\[2pt]
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.06\linewidth}}{Methods} &
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.005\linewidth}}{M} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.02\linewidth}}{D} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.115\linewidth}}{No. of Parameters} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.1\linewidth}}{RRMSE $(\%)$} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.14\linewidth}}{relative error in the first block $(\%)$} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.14\linewidth}}{relative error in the second block $(\%)$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.05\linewidth}}{time (s)}\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Method 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{20+20} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Method 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{105} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Method 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Method 4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}


Do you employ the IEEEtran document class? Please advise.

yes \documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}. I use this line

Please clarify your first objective: Do you want 3 sub-columns each below columns 5, 6, and 7?

yes, under column 5 (RRMSE) I need three sub columns. and Similarly for the next two columns (6 and 7).

Something like this?

Note that I've eliminated all \multicolumn{2}{...}{...} wrappers.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,calc}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X'
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{>{\Centering}p{3.4cm}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
   % '3.4cm' obtained by trial and error

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\centering

\caption{Performance on Test Data} \label{tbl:sim}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{@{} % "1\textwidth" seems needlessly wide
         l c c 
         >{\Centering}p{\widthof{Parameters}} 
         *{9}{C}  
         >{\Centering}p{\widthof{Time}} 
         @{}}

\multicolumn{14}{c}{A. Polynomial and Training sample, $N=10{,}000$} \\
\addlinespace
\toprule
Methods & M & D & No.\ of Parameters & 
\mc{RRMSE (\%)} & 
\mc{Relative error in the first block (\%)} & 
\mc{Relative error in the second block (\%)} &
Time (s) \\
\cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-13}
 & & & & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C & \\
\midrule
Method 1 & 20+20 & 3  &     & \\
Method 2 & 100   & 10 & 105 & \\
Method 3 & 10    & 3  &     & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & \\
Method 4 & 10    & 3  &     & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}


Addendum: By widening the table to \textwidth, one could simplify and streamline the appearance of the header rows significantly.

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\newcommand\mytab[1]{% for use in columns 4 and 14
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}

\caption{Performance on Test Data} \label{tbl:sim}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l ccc *{9}{C} c @{}}
\multicolumn{14}{c}{A. Polynomial and Training sample, $N=10{,}000$} \\[1ex]
\toprule
Methods & M & D & \mytab{No.\ of\\Parameters} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{RRMSE (\%)} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Relative error in 1st block (\%)} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Relative error in 2nd block (\%)} &
\mytab{Time\\(s)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-13}
 & & & & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C & \\
\midrule
Method 1 & 20+20 & 3  &     & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & \\
Method 2 & 100   & 10 & 105 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & \\
Method 3 & 10    & 3  &     & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & \\
Method 4 & 10    & 3  &     & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table*}

\end{document}


@Neuling - Many thanks for the "checkmark". :-) Do note that I've gone ahead and posted an addendum with a different, and in my view possibly superior, layout.
